# How can I implement a live Javascript Regex for phone numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text box and it says "Phone:" as the standard here for phone number is (XXX)-XXX-XXXX
I'd like to have a javascript that automatically puts my numbers into that format if it's not in that format, so if you typed 9993334444 then it would change it automatically on the fly as I'm typing to (999)-333-4444 I have looked around Google for Javascript Phone Regex to no success, maybe a Regex isn't what I'm looking for?

Comment: This is really not trivial to solve! If the user entered "999" than you probably want to show "(999)-" in the input field. If the user then enters <BACKSPACE> you probably want to show "(99" in the field. Another tricky part might be copy&pasted text.

I once had to implement a similar problem for a client, but it was much work to do and in the end the result was not REALLY a handy solution. :(

Comment: You're also saying that you'll never be using this software in a locale with different standards for phone numbers. Just let the users do it themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to add an onkeyup event with a regex like

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/^\(?([0-9][0-9][0-9]){1}\)?-?([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]){1}-?([0-9][0-9][0-9]){1}$/, '($1)-$2-$3');
```

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/R8enX/

```
/ means start/end a regex string
^ means start of matching string
$ means end of matching string
? means 0 or 1 instances (make braces and dashes optional)
[0-9] means any single digit
(x){1} tags x as an expression that we can reference in the replacement with a $ sign
```

EDIT: realized I missed a digit on the last group of numbers, the jsfiddle will only work (properly) with 3 digits in the last group

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the fact that jsfiddle will only work properly with 3 digits in the last group cause I just tried the code and it worked fine :) I didn't know about onkeyup events, I thought I had to use Onclick so you taught me something today. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To build somewhat on @Andrews answer you can check for a valid (local)phone number via this method.  If the number is shorter or larger than 10 digits, it collapses back into an invalid number

-

```
<input type="text" onBlur="localNumber(this.value)"/>

<div id="output"></div>
```

-

```
<script>

var localNumber = function(str){

    repl = str.replace(/^([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})$/, "($1)-$2-$3");
    outp = document.getElementById('output');

    if( repl.match(/\W/) )
    {
        outp.innerHTML = repl;
    }
    else
    {
        outp.innerHTML = 'Invalid number for this region';
    }

}

</script>
```